# Bash script for periodically launching and killing an app

Tags: command-line, bash, kill

I have a short script which should launch an app, wait for an hour, then kill it and wait for a minute. It only starts the app. I tried to run the script both as a normal user and root, but nothing helped.

```
while (true); do
  ./app
  sleep 3600
  pkill -f app
  sleep 60
done
```

Comment: when you launch the app you need to put it into the background using `./app &`  or else the script will never reach seeing the sleep step until after the app exits

Comment: I think it's better to use ```$!``` to get the PID of ```app``` instead of getting it via searching through the process names with pkill. But first you have to put it into background to be able to get it's pid via ```$!```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all commands are executed from the first line to the last in order. So as `@Scott Stensland` mentoined you have to put it into background via `&` (ampersand) to make the timer start.

And furthermore I think getting the PID of your app via searching through process names is a dangerous practice since you might accidentally kill a program which contains the string `app` in its name. So a safer way is to use the variable `!` to get the PID . So your modified script should now looks like this :

```
while (true); do
  ./app &
  app_pid=$!
  sleep 3600
  kill $app_pid
  sleep 60
done
```

When you put a process into background via `&` it goes into the [job](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-jobs-command-examples-usage-syntax/) list of the parent bash process , and via `!` you can get the PID of the last job.So it's safe.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using the `timeout` command:

```
NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
       Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

ex.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  timeout 1h ./app
  sleep 1m
done
```